# Modify batch script to conditionally write files

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file below copied from internet.
Need some help with it.
The batch takes the output from a command or other batch and echos the output to both to console and to a specified file. Echoing to console is fine but is there a way to write to the file only when a condition is met? May be if the echoed text contains some string say "LOGMESSAGE".
So if 2 messages were echoed by the command or batch,
Message 1: "Hello, how are you?"
Message 2: "LOGMESSAGE Thanks, I am good."

The Message 1 should be displayed only on console and the Message 2 should be displayed both on console and in the file.

```
@ECHO OFF
:: Check Windows version
IF NOT "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" GOTO Syntax

:: Keep variables local
SETLOCAL

:: Check command line arguments
SET Append=0
IF /I [%1]==[-a] (
    SET Append=1
    SHIFT
)
IF     [%1]==[] GOTO Syntax
IF NOT [%2]==[] GOTO Syntax

:: Test for invalid wildcards
SET Counter=0
FOR /F %%A IN ('DIR /A /B %1 2^>NUL') DO CALL :Count "%%~fA"
IF %Counter% GTR 1 (
    SET Counter=
    GOTO Syntax
)

:: A valid filename seems to have been specified
SET File=%1

:: Check if a directory with the specified name exists
DIR /AD %File% >NUL 2>NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    SET File=
    GOTO Syntax
)

:: Specify /Y switch for Windows 2000 / XP COPY command
SET Y=
VER | FIND "Windows NT" > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET Y=/Y

:: Flush existing file or create new one if -a wasn't specified
IF %Append%==0 (COPY %Y% NUL %File% > NUL 2>&1)

:: Actual TEE
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A IN ('FIND /N /V ""') DO (
    >  CON    ECHO.%%B
    >> %File% ECHO.%%B
)

:: Done
ENDLOCAL
GOTO:EOF


:Count
SET /A Counter += 1
SET File=%1
GOTO:EOF


:Syntax
ECHO.
ECHO Tee.bat,  Version 2.11a for Windows NT 4 / 2000 / XP
ECHO Display text on screen and redirect it to a file simultaneously
ECHO.
IF NOT "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" ECHO Usage:  some_command  ¦  TEE.BAT  [ -a ]  filename
IF NOT "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" GOTO Skip
ECHO Usage:  some_command  ^|  TEE.BAT  [ -a ]  filename
:Skip
ECHO.
ECHO Where:  "some_command" is the command whose output should be redirected
ECHO         "filename"     is the file the output should be redirected to
ECHO         -a             appends the output of the command to the file,
    ECHO                        rather than overwriting the file
    ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO Written by Rob van der Woude
ECHO http://www.robvanderwoude.com
ECHO Modified by Kees Couprie
ECHO http://kees.couprie.org
ECHO and Andrew Cameron
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
:: Actual TEE
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A IN ('FIND /N /V ""') DO (
    >  CON    ECHO.%%B
    echo "%%B"|find "LOGMESSAGE" >nul
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 >> %File% ECHO.%%B
)
...
```

The extra FIND attempts to locate the target string in the message to be recorded. If it is found, `errorlevel` will be set to 0, non-0 otherwise.

Do not try to use the syntax `"if %errorlevel%==0"` here since it's in a statement block and that construct will not interpret the errorlevel from the FIND, but as it stood when the `FOR` was parsed.

---

To suppress the "don't write to log" flag, try

:: Actual TEE
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A IN ('FIND /N /V ""') DO (
  SET message=%%B
  IF DEFINED message SET message=!message:LOGMESSAGE=!

> CON    ECHO(!message!
>     IF "%%B"=="!message!" >> %File% ECHO(%%B
>   )
>   ENDLOCAL

which should delete the string "logmesssage" (in either case) and - this bit seems reversed - NOT log the line to the file, but send the line, with the flag "logmessage" expunged, to the console. Perhaps "skiplog" would be a better string...

Comment: the solution worked. But does append empty lines to the file. But it does the job Thanks.

Comment: Hi @peter, the prompt and the command also gets flushed to the file. Like so:
C:\>echo LOGMESSAGE bbbbbbbb
LOGMESSAGE bbbbbbbb
Is it possible to get only the actual output LOGMESSAGE bbbbbbbb in this case?

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps it's an OS-version difference. I'm using WIN7 and poked a `DIR` listing through each - the original and then the one with the changed `FOR` block. Other than excluding a different string (one of the filenames) I got no added empty lines. Curious...

Comment: Can't get your results. I don't get the prompt you mention.